# How do I tag text with metadata for later filtering in a long document?

Tags: pdf, search, metadata, tags, knowledge-management

I have some large PDFs on the order of a few thousand pages each.

Instead of searching constantly with Ctrl+F or keeping a directory of page numbers, I was wondering if there's some simple way to tag text in the documents up front, and then filter with those same tags later. I’d like to avoid writing software to solve this issue, but I’m open to hearing ideas regarding scripting or XML.